# Directory Auto Sorting(rename, too) by Using PHP

Tags: php

I want to make code about auto sorting and renaming.

(directory: /public_html/file/)
Folder Names:

1
2
3
4
5

filename: aurosort.php

When I delete folder name "3" by using autosort.php, I want to add code that rename folder "4" to "3" and "5" to "4" auto.

Comment: can you please share your code with us? what is your problem? at which point do you struggle? use `glob` to get the directories sorted by number and use a loop to check the names and if there is a hole somewhere. then rename the remaining directories.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you should try something using dir funtions, like:

```
$root = "/public_html/file/";
function removeAndAutosort($rdir);
{
    if (is_dir($rdir)) {
      rmdir($rdir);
    }
    $dir = scandir($root);
    for($i=0; $i<=count($dir); ++$i) {
      !is_dir($root.$i) ? rename($root.$i+1,$root.$i) : continue;
    }
}
```

The function will receive the name of the dir to remove, check if it exists and then remove it.

Next, it makes an array with every dir in the tree since the removal, iterates over its `count` value (should be the number of dirs + 1) and checks if given directory exists again. If does, the iteration proceeds. If don't, it'll rename the next directory with the name of the deleted one.

Please, note that I tested this code on a simulated environment that may not match your context, and **I'm assuming all your directories have number names**.